# Считать строку, используя стримы

Tags: java, java-stream

**Есть такой файл с такими строками:**

> картошка капуста
>
> молоко хлеб
>
> хлеб лук

Хочу получить `List<List<>>` , то есть в листе должно быть слова строки.

Пытался сделать так:

```
 Files.lines(Paths.get(ReadFile.class.getResource(path).toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .flatMap(s->Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")))
                .filter(s->!s.isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Но так записывается все слова файла. Требуется на стримах это реализовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<List<String>> list = Files.lines(Paths.get(ReadFile.class.getResource(path).toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

Вывод:

> [[картошка, капуста], [молоко, хлеб], [хлеб, лук]]